# Determine use of CRYPTOPP_BOOL_AESNI_INTRINSICS_AVAILABLE at runtime

Tags: linux, crypto++

We are using Crypto++ 5.6.3 and compiling with g++ on CentOS 6. Is it possible to determine at runtime if our application has linked with a libcryptopp that was built with `CRYPTOPP_BOOL_AESNI_INTRINSICS_AVAILABLE` as `1` or `0`?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to determine at runtime if our application has linked with a libcryptopp that was built with CRYPTOPP_BOOL_AESNI_INTRINSICS_AVAILABLE as 1 or 0?

No, its not. As a matter of fact, you won't even be able to tell if you are using AES-NI or the software implementation.

There's been some talk about stashing `CXXFLAGS` away for future use like this (and printing them from the `cryptest.exe` program), but its very low priority. So low there's been no bug report on it to stage the work.

***EDIT***: now open on the Crypto++ mailing list: [GNUmakefile and 'make flag' recipe](http://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cryptopp-users/VxTTf9sT8Wk).

---

The Crypto++ test suite prints a value for the macro. It comes from [validat1.cpp](http://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/validat1.cpp#L311), around line 310:

```
cout << "AESNI_INTRINSICS == " << CRYPTOPP_BOOL_AESNI_INTRINSICS_AVAILABLE << endl;
```

But as I think you are aware, the library build settings and your build settings could be different.

---

It also noteworthy that Crypto++ uses a makefile, while distros often build using Autotools. The distros select their own flags, and they may be different from the Crypto++ makefile. When using the distro, you may be able to check a `*.pc` file or similar.

Related, we test on CentOS 5 through CentOS 7. CentOS 5 is a nice machine because its got GCC 4.1, and that version of GCC kind of particular about some things. For example, it cannot consume `-march=native`.

Comment: Thank you, that confirmed my take on the matter after looking through the source.  It would be nice to have an extern flag available indicating the status of this.

Comment: @PhilC - What if we added a Makefile rule to write the `CXXFLAGS` to a file for you. You will have to perform an extra step (like `make flags`) but it will get them into a file for you (like `cxxflags.h`).

Comment: We have 2 builds of the library, one with AESNI available and one without.  We build two versions of our program statically linking with each of these. What we really need is something available at runtime, like an extern bool / int flag that is set based on the compiler flag. We ended up adding a compiler directive ourselves when we link with the library specifically built without AESNI. 
Thank you

Comment: *"We have 2 builds of the library, one with AESNI available and one without..."* - OK, I see what you are doing... You want to use AES-NI if available, and fallback to C++ if not available. Unfortunately, AES is not setup that way. On the other hand, I am aware of use case, and we took it into considerations for classes like [BLAKE2](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/blake2.cpp). The header is clean so the interface never changes; and the implementation switching occurs in the CPP file at runtime (see `s_pfn` - it holds an SSE4, SSE2 or CXX impl at runtime).